# Does water therapy make the body much more able to absorb nutrients from food?

Tags: medical-science

[Undergroundhealthreporter.com](http://undergroundhealthreporter.com/drinking-water-in-the-morning/) claims:

> It has long been known that drinking water first thing in the morning on an empty stomach purifies the body’s internal system. An especially important result of this treatment is that it cleanses the colon, which makes the body much more able to absorb nutrients from food.

It it true?

Comment: Related question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4098/does-indian-water-therapy-have-healing-effects

Comment: I suspect not, the body has a lot of "hardware" for maintaining the correct internal environment and does a pretty good job of it under most conditions that aren't extreme (such as extreme food/water deprivation, salt/water overdose, etc|

Answer (score 4):

The primary problem is that the idea of "cleansing the colon" making the body "much more able to absorb nutrients from food" doesn't work because the colon doesn't do much nutrient absorption.  [Almost all the nutrients](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/health-topics/Anatomy/your-digestive-system/Pages/anatomy.aspx) get absorbed in the small intestine.

There is also the problem that the body is constantly producing water in the digestive system, and most of the water we drink doesn't reach the colon anyway.

As a rule of thumb, though, any advice based on the premise that doing something "cleanses" something in the body is almost certainly nonsense, especially if they are vague about what exactly is being cleaned out and why it makes a difference.  Your body is pretty good at cleansing itself, and if there is something it cannot get rid of you need a more serious intervention.

Edit: link changed to be from the NIH.

Comment: The source cited in this answer is just someone's blog that cites no references of its own. Can you find a more credible, peer-reviewed, or widely accepted source? I don't doubt your conclusion, but we need at least a more rigorous source than the one in the original claim.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I changed the link to one from the NIH.  I assume that is credible enough?

Comment: That is much better.

Comment: LOL - Did you consider that "cleanses" are very effective in cleaning the money out of your wallet?